# How do I work out this derivative?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, derivatives, vector-spaces

I'm dealing with minimising a loss function, I don't understand how this derivative is calculated in particular.$$\frac{\partial}{\partial v_c}u_x^Tv_c=u_x$$

I understand how partial derivatives work for variables in $\mathbb R $, but here $v_c$ is a vector in $\mathbb R^d $ and $u_x$ is a matrix in $\mathbb R^{d\times v} $. Why was the transpose removed when calculating the derivative ?

Comment: Never post unsearchable pictures.  Instead typeset in *MathJax*.

Comment: I've edited your question as best I understood it, viz. @DavidG.Stork's observation (see also [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) guide). Please edit if I got your question wrong.

Comment: I may have misunderstood one thing. I change your $*$ to $\times$, but now I've made it look like you want $u_x$ to be a matrix. Then again, maybe you did. We can't define $u_x^Tv_c$ if $u_x$ is a vector of $dv$ components if $d\ne1$.

Comment: @J.G. Yes, I'm sorry I meant it to be a matrix. Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M$ be a matrix, let $x$ be a vector, and consider $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} M^Tx,$$
assuming the dimensions of $M$ and $x$ allow for $M^Tx$ to be computable. This is the derivative of a vector with respect to a vector (since $M^Tx$ is a vector and $x$ is a vector). There are two ways of computing this (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Layout_conventions). You always take the resulting vector ($M^Tx)$ and then for each element in this vector, you differentiate for each element in $x$. After you've done all the elements in $x$, you get your first row OR column. Then you move on to the next element in $M^Tx$ and repeat, to find the next row OR column. Now whether you are using rows or columns determines the answer.

Now, say we determine the rows.

So, the first element of $M^Tx$ equals $M_{1, 1}x_1 + M_{2, 1}x_2 + ...$, and so on. The second element equals $M_{1, 2}x_1 + M_{2,2}x_2 + ...$, and so on.

Now you take the derivative of these elements with respect to the $x$-variables, element-wise. So, for $x_1$, you clearly get $M_{1,1}$. For $x_2$, you get $M_{2,1}$. So, you can tell that you just get the first column of $M$. This column is the first *row* of your answer (as I mentioned above). So your first row in the answer is the first column of $M$. Now to find the next row in your answer, you can repeat the process, and you'll see the answer is the second column of $M$.

So, clearly, the answer is just $M^T$.

Let's look at an example of this:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}  \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \end{pmatrix} ^T\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}  \begin{pmatrix}   1x_1 + 3x_2 \\ 2x_1 + 4x_2\end{pmatrix}  = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 \\ 2 & 4 \end{pmatrix} $$

Here, the transpose is not removed (the last matrix on the right is just the original matrix transposed). But if we used the columns-approach, then the transpose would have been removed. So it's all about convention.